# create mysql trigger in shell command line

Tags: mysql, command-line

I need to create a mysql trigger in command line

This sql working good in mysql console:

```php
$sql = "
    USE DB1;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_trigger;
    DELIMITER $$
    CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON tbl1
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO DB2.tbl2 (column1)
        VALUES (1234);
    END$$
    DELIMITER ;
";

$cmd = 'mysql -sse "'.$sql.'";';

//put all in one line to avoid shell errors
$cmd = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n|\t|\s+/m', " ", $cmd);
        
exec("($cmd) 2>&1", $output, $result);
```

This thrown an mysql error

> ERROR 1064 (42000) at line 1: You have an error in your SQL syntax;
> check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the
> right syntax to use near 'END' at line 1

I have also tried with `DELIMITER //` ... same error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The solution:** change `DELIMITER $$` with `\d $$` (after spending two days with this :( )

In php must use `\\d $$`

```php
$sql = "
    USE DB1;
    DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS my_trigger;
    \\d $$
    CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger AFTER UPDATE ON tbl1
     FOR EACH ROW BEGIN 
        INSERT INTO DB2.tbl2 (column1)
        VALUES (1234);
    END$$
    \\d ;
";

$cmd = 'mysql -sse "'.$sql.'";';

//put all in one line to avoid shell errors
$cmd = preg_replace('/\r\n|\r|\n|\t|\s+/m', " ", $cmd);

exec("($cmd) 2>&1", $output, $result);
```

> It seem that when we put all in one line only work the shorthand of delimiter `\d`

Comment: Thank you for this, I've spent awhile trying to figure out why this wouldn't work on the command line like you show.